# Does such an analytic function exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Consider the following region in the complex plane
$$
R=\{re^{i\theta}:r>0, 0<\theta<\gamma<\frac{\pi}{2}\}
$$
Then does there exist a function  $f(z)$, which is analytic in $R$ and continuous to the boundary, such that we have the following estimates on the boundary
$$
cr^a\leq|f(r)|\leq Cr^a,~~~ r>0,
$$
for some positive constant $a, c, C$, and also 
$$
|f(re^{i\gamma})|\leq C,~~~ r>0 ?
$$

In particular, I was wondering if a form like $z^{g(z)}h(z)$ with some choice of $g(z),h(z)$ would work.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**Thanks to Julián Aguirr, who provided a nice and simple example. Later, however, I found the function I was looking for need to be bounded  only on the upper boundary of the region $R$, and unbounded (behaves also like $r^a$ near $\infty$) in $R$. I'm really appreciated if someone would point it out. Thanks again!

Comment: @copper.hat I think that $c>0$ was to be included as an assumption here or else you are right.

Comment: @copper.hat, sorry, I didn't make it clear, I'm looking for nontrivial examples, fixed it now. thanks to Angelo too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=e^{iz}z^a$, $a>0$. Then
$$
|f(r)|=r^a,\quad r>0,
$$
and
$$
|f(re^{i\gamma})|=r^ae^{-r\sin\gamma}\le \Bigl(\frac{a}{\sin\gamma}\Bigr)^ae^{-a},\quad r>0.
$$

Comment: Dear Aguirre, I notice that your function  is actually bounded for all $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $0<\theta\leq \gamma$, right? However, is there possible to find a function which is bounded only on $\{re^{i\gamma}: r>0\}$, and unbounded on the interior of $R$? Thanks again.

Comment: More precisely, I mean a function behaves like $r^a$ near $\infty$ also in the region $R$, but bounded on the upper boundary.

Comment: That is a different problem. Let me think about it.